# Read files in compute instance through cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to access the files present in compute engine VM. I have to read file from GCE and need to transform files into GCS using python SDK in cloud Dataflow.
It'll be help full if any one suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions.

1. If your transformation can stand on the VM (no need of horizontal scalability), you can run your Beam pipeline directly on the VM with [`DirectRunner` runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/)
2. If you want to use Dataflow, you have to put your file in a accessible storage: Google Cloud Storage. You can use [rsync if you have to sync a directory with the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync), and  you can cron it on your VM. Then build your pipepline to read the file from the bucket and process it
3. If your file is "ingestable" in BigQuery, you can load it into BigQuery and perform your transformation through SQL and [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), and think the result in other table and then [extract it to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data)

With more details on wishes and contraints, we could refine the answer.

Comment: I would like to read file in VM after transformation output file will be placed into gcs. 
How we can proceed can you please explain me in bit detail please.

Comment: You can't read file stored into a VM with Dataflow. You have to externalize the file -> Put it in Cloud Storage. (Bullet point 2). However, you can also run your Beam pipeline on your VM (bullet point 1). By the way, the pipeline can read your file stored into the VM and then push the transformation to Cloud Storage. For this, the main question is: Is your pipeline can be performed on a single VM? Indeed, Dataflow is required for large and parallel data processing. But for a "simple" transformations, it can stand into a VM, a Function, a Cloud Run,...